# Setting environment variables for accessing in PHP when using Apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have a Linux environment and I have a PHP Web Application that conditionally runs based on environment variables using `getenv` in PHP. I need to know how these environment variables need to be set for the application to work correctly. I am not sure how to set this up on Apache.

Also, I need to be able to configure separate environment variables for each domain separately.

Please advice on how can I achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146354/setting-php-variables-in-httpd-conf

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
<VirtualHost hostname:80>
   ...
   SetEnv VARIABLE_NAME variable_value
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: was not in my $_ENV array, for retreiving value see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378871/set-application-env-via-virtual-host-config-and-read-this-in-php

Comment: @i_a you can access the value in PHP with `getenv('VARIABLE_NAME')`

Comment: in xampp on windows the file will be C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: @i_a On my machine the value can also be found in the `$_SERVER` variable.

Comment: Also you can use you `Include` or `IncludeOptional` if you don't want to change vhost.conf

Answer (score 36):

You can also do this in a .htaccess file assuming they are enabled on the website.

```
SetEnv KOHANA_ENV production
```

Would be all you need to add to a .htaccess to add the environment variable

Comment: is this any different from using a .env file such as the way laravel does this? Does this make it any way less secure? I ask this because I'm building the same backend structure with multiple frameworks (laravel, express, django, etc.) and some developers of those other languages say its' not appropriate to use .env and that the "server config" should be used instead, or doing it through the command line, heroku style

Answer (score 18):

If your server is Ubuntu and Apache version is 2.4

> Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

Then you export variables in `/etc/apache2/envvars` location.

Just like this below line, you need to add an extra line in `/etc/apache2/envvars`

`export MY_ENV_NAME=myEnvValue`

Comment: If you are coming to this question for a LAMP stack, this is probably what you want to use. Good answer btw!

Answer (score 10):

Unbelievable, but on httpd 2.2 on centos 6.4 this works.

Export env vars in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

```
export mydocroot=/var/www/html
```

Then simply do this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot ${mydocroot}
</VirtualHost>
```

Then finally....

```
service httpd restart;
```

Comment: Not sure why in MacOSX's apache, the `DocumentRoot ${mydocroot}` simply write it as a string vs evaluating it and place it in the vhost