# Uploading .docx using mime types

Tags: php, yii, mime-types

I've been using the built-in `mimeTypes`validator for uploading files through Yii. I can't seem to get .docx files or .rtf files to be accepted though. Currently I have this code:

**Model**

```
array('file', 'file', 'on' => 'insert', 'safe'=>true, 'maxSize'=> 512000, 'maxFiles'=> 1, 
                    'mimeTypes' => 'application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, text/rtf, text/plain',
                    'tooLarge'=> 'File cannot be larger than 500KB.',
                    'wrongMimeType'=> 'Format must be:<code>.doc</code>  <code>.docx</code> <code>.txt</code> <code>.rtf</code>'),
```

I've added the .docx extension to Yii's mimeTypes.php file with this line:

```
'docx'=>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
```

I've also added this to my apache/conf/mime.type

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx
```

I've also read around on the topic and seen that often these files are regarded as zips and added the mimeType `application/octet-stream` and `application/zip` and it still won't upload.

I've also echoed out the mime_type Yii is seeing and it matches the settings I have inside the model.

I'm just a bit lost on what else and where else to try and fix this. So any help from more experienced people would be great

Thanks

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of [`CFileValidator::validateFile()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#validateFile-detail) you'll notice that Yii will either use [`finfo_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) (since PHP 5.3.0) or [`mime_content_type()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) to find out the MIME type of your file.

- [`finfo_open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) will usually use the bundled magic database in PHP. But you can override this by setting a `MAGIC` environment variable as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php).
- [`mime_content_type()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) will use the magic file as specified in the [`mime_magic.magicfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mime-magic.configuration.php#ini.mime-magic.magicfile) configuration setting

So if you check your PHP version, you can debug further or supply your custom magic file.

Comment: I have PHP 5.3.0 -> phpinfo tells me that fileinfo support is enabled. In my php.ini it lists the magic.mime file at mime_magic.magicfile = "C:\xampp\php\extras\magic". But there is no file there. So This to me would suggest that it uses the bundled magic database you talk of. Although I have no clue where this file would be, i checked within PHPMyAdmin and the PHP directories of XAMPP or what the next step would be?? - Appreciate you taking the time to help me too!

Comment: I found a "magic" file in my apache/conf/ this is what it had for msword:

# msword: file(1) magic for MS Word files
#
# Contributor claims:
# Reversed-engineered MS Word magic numbers
#

0 string  \376\067\0\043   application/msword
0 string  \333\245-\0\0\0   application/msword

# disable this one because it applies also to other
# Office/OLE documents for which msword is not correct. See PR#2608.
#0 string  \320\317\021\340\241\261 application/msword

Comment: So does it work? You could try to user Apache's magic file you found: Just add something like `SetEnv MAGIC /etc/apache/conf/magic` to the `<VirtualHost>` section of your webserver config.

Comment: It doesn't work with Docx files. .rtf + .docs are fine. I will try as you suggest. I didn't see anything inside Apache's magic file relating to .docx files though?

Comment: Maybe this also helps: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45141. There's a link to a magic file.

Comment: Added: <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
SetEnv MAGIC /etc/apache/conf/magic
</VirtualHost>

to the httpd.conf, restarted XAMPP. Still couldn't upload a .docx file. Tried setting the environment to the magic file (which doesn't sem to show anything about .docx and also changed the environment to the mime.type file that does list the .docx mime. same result.