# how to Access to environment variable using php

Tags: php, environment-variables

I have set a custom environment variable in debian using below command :

```
$ export my_var=1
```

I want to read this variable value using php. I have tried :

```
echo getenv('my_var');
```

if I call the php code from the command line using php command it is ok but when I access to php code using apache it doesn't echo anything.

Why is it so?

Comment: have you defined that variable in the apache envvars? (assuming you're using apache as your webserver) or just from the command line?

Comment: just from the command line.

Comment: In that case, update your apache envvars config file to set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so, because your console has its own context with its own environment variables and Apache its own. Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php) answer to set the environment variables in apache.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i wrote a library to get values from environment variables and parse to the PHP data types. This library can be used to parse environment variables to PHP data types (like the casting to integer, float, null, boolean), parse the complex data structures like a JSON string and more with the contribution of the commnunity.

The library is available here: https://github.com/jpcercal/environment

Put your environment variables into "/etc/environment" and "/etc/apache2/envvars", after restart your Apache Server and load your environment variables to operational system:

```
# source /etc/environment
# source /etc/apache2/envvars
```

If you are running the application using a CLI basically export the variables:

```
export YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME="yourValue"
```

And to get the values from environment variable (independently of the environment CLI, Apache, Nginx, PHP Built-in Server and more) to do it:

```
<?php
// ...
require "vendor/autoload.php";
// ...
var_dump(Cekurte\Environment\Environment::get("YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME"));
```

Enjoy it.