# Environment detection in Laravel 4.1+

Tags: php, laravel

[Laravel 4.1 removed the feature](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1) to use the domain for detecting what environment the app is running in. Reading the docs they now suggest using host names. However, to me that seems cumbersome if you are working in a team. Should everyone change the `bootstrap/start.php` file and add their own host name to be able to run the app in a dev environment? Also, what if you want to have two different environments on the same machine?

How to best detect the environment if you are working in a team in Laravel 4.1+?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is my settings from **bootstrap/start.php** file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() use($app) {
    return getenv('ENV') ?: ($app->runningInConsole() ? 'local' : 'production');
});
```

Instead of default array, this method in my case is returning closure with ternary. That way I got more flexibility in choosing desired environment. You can use switch statement also. Laravel will read return value and configure itself.
With **getenv** native function, I am just listening for a given environment. If my app is on the server, then it will "pick" server configurations. If locally, then it will pick local (or development)
And don't forget to create custom directories for you environemnts in **app/config**
There is also testing env, which is choosen automatically, every time you are unit testing app.

Laravel makes working with environments really fun.

**UPDATE:**

With environments we are mostly cencerned about db credentials.

For production I use **Fortrabbit**, so when configuring new app on server, fortrabbit is generating those values for me. I just need to declare them. e.g. DB of just database or db... Or DB_HOST or HOST ... 
Locally, those values are the one you use for your localhost/mysql settings.

Comment: That looks beautiful! I didn't have the "ENV" variable though. I suppose you have to set it in the apache config somewhere? Do you mind adding instructions for that in your answer?

Comment: Inspired by your answer I read the docs again and found they are actually suggesting something very similar as well, but using $_SERVER['ENV'] instead of getenv('ENV'). http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: I guess getenv("ENV") is pointing to $_SERVER["ENV"]. So use what works. And please accept answer if you like it.

Comment: I didn't really get your update. You never set the "ENV" variable? Not even locally? By the way, Fortrabbit looks great.

Comment: Hey Simon - let me clarify to you. I did set "ENV" variable - it is called "local" or "development" or whatever.In Laravel env variable is the name of the folder in which you will place you environment settings. That folder should be placed inside app/config/ directory.
Laravel will read content of that folder. Default environment is production, and Laravel reads everything what is inside app/config/.
So you just "steal" some settings, place them under new directory and tell laravel in bootstrap/start.php what is the name of you new environment name. Clear ?

Comment: Sure, thanks! I do use special config folders depending on the environment that the app is currently running in, however so far I found them pretty limited. Most of my config is kept out of version control and placed in the *env-name*.env.php files in the root folder.

Comment: What I was looking for was where to set this ENV variable. You can do it in apache's virtual server conf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php

Comment: For NGINX you can set ENV by adding `fastcgi_param   ENV  production; ` to `location ~ \.php$ {` in the vhost.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

In Laravel 5.0 environment detection is no longer needed in the same way. In the `.env` file you can simply have a variable for which environment the app should run in.

**Old answer for Laravel <= 4.2**

What I ended up doing is very close to what carousel suggested. Anyway, thought I would share it. Here is the relevant part of our `bootstrap/start.php` file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function ()
{
    if($app->runningInConsole())
        return "development";

    $validEnvironments = array("development", "staging", "production");
    if (in_array(getenv('APP_ENV'), $validEnvironments)) {
        return getenv('APP_ENV');
    }
    throw new Exception("Environment variable not set or is not valid. See developer manual for further information.");
});
```

This way all team members have to declare an environment variable somewhere. I haven't really decided if throwing an exception if the environment variable is not set or just default to production is the best thing. However, with the above, it's easy to change.

Comment: This doesn't work when using the command line. Carousel's answer takes `$app->runningInConsole()` into consideration and uses `local`. This allows you to run `php artisan`. With your way I don't think you can.

Comment: You can actually specify the environment with the `artisan --env` switch. However, I agree that Carousel's solution is better. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just use `'dev' => '*.local'` and it works. I haven't 100% tested in a team situation but I think it'd work (big assumption alert:) assuming you're on OSX and get the default `Alexs-iMac.local`-like hostname.

As for faking an environment, I'm not sure it's really supported. It'll be doable, but in general the whole point of environments is that dev has entirely different needs to production and the two are mutually exclusive. Having the ability to switch on one physical environment seems counter to that goal.

Comment: I don't think that will work on all platforms. I have windows and my current host name is "hhp"

Comment: I certainly concede that point. You could try seeing if the detectEnvironment array can cascade though. Set prod first, then `'dev' => '*'` or something. That said, you've accepted using environment variables answer so I'll leave quietly now :)

Comment: What do you mean by cascade?

Comment: Well I don't think I actually mean cascade so much as do later rules override previous rules? So like I said, if you had `['prod' => 'servername.com', 'dev' => '*']` then does it work as expected and correctly see prod on prod and everything else as dev or does it work the other way around? Worth looking into anyway.

Comment: Ah! That might work. However, there might be security issues having the dev environment as default.

Comment: Very true. That said, the answer you accepted does the same thing. Of course, if you know all your teams' hostnames, you can do `'dev' => ['hhp', 'Alexs-iMac.local', '...']`

Comment: Yeah I suppose. Would be nice to be able to avoid having to constantly change that file though as other people joins or if new computers is bought/used. I will add another answer soon with what I ended up doing, very close to the accepted however.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4.1 and 4.2 detects the environments through the machine names specified in the "bootstrap/start.php" file.

For example, in my case the config becomes:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('Victor.local', 'Victor-PC'),
));
```

This means that Laravel will use the 'local' environment settings for both machines: 'Victor.local' (a Mac) and 'Victor-PC' (Windows).

This way you can regsiter several machines to work as local environment. Other environments can be registered too.

In order to know the current machine name, you can use the following PHP code:

`<?php echo gethostname(); ?>`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'youdomain_local')
    {
        return 'local';
    }elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'youdomain_team')
    {
        return 'team';
    }else{
        return 'production';
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem is that HTTP_HOST is very easy to spoof.

Answer (score 0):

what i did is, make dir `app/config/local` and use code

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost"?"local":"production";
});
```

For localhost and online.

Comment: This is very easy to 'hack'. You can try it yourself by redirecting localhost to your live domain in your hosts file. That would make it possible to run your live site in 'local' mode which in turn might make it possible to see all your db config and passwords etc.

Comment: This throws an error for me when using the CLI (Artisan), as it can't access HTTP_HOST

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like that production was default, so I made it anything other than live server will go to local configs:

in bootstrap/start.php :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    if (gethostname() !== 'live_server_hostname'){
        return 'local';
    } else {
        return 'production';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bootstrap/start.php` define this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() use($app) {

    $enviromentsHosts = [
        'localhost',
        'local',
    ];

    if ($app->runningInConsole() || in_array($app['request']->getHost(), $enviromentsHosts)) {

        return 'local';

    } else {

        return 'production';
    }
});
```

I believe it is better to use only the resources of `Laravel 4`