# Why is getenv() only returning a variable when run from the terminal, not via web server

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a custom environment variable for environment detection in my PHP application. I've set the variable system-wide in **/etc/environment**, rebooted, and checked that it is visible through the terminal using **printenv**.

I've also checked that it is visible when running PHP at the command line:

```
php -r 'echo getenv("LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT");'

//returns 'true' as expected
```

But when I try from a web page script, the variable is not found:

```
var_dump(getenv("LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT"));

//returns 'boolean false' (not expected)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.2.

Why is the variable not visible from a web script, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your using apache server, I think its down to Apache being restricted from the System Environment variables.. for security.

You should set env variables on apache like `SetEnv LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT true` or even better `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development` is generally considered the standard.

Comment: thanks, makes sense and this works. In my case on Ubuntu, I set this in the appropriate Apache config file in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/

Answer (score 1):

For those using PHP-FPM, ensure the [`clear_env` setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) is set to `false` within your FPM pool config file, otherwise the environment variables will be wiped before PHP has access to them.

The PHP CLI may not use FPM and therefore wouldn't be subject to the `clear_env` setting, which would explain why environment variables might be visible when scripts are run in the shell but not in the browser via PHP-FPM.