# PHP script runs in terminal, but doesn't run on the webpage

Tags: php, macos, webserver

I have a webpage: test.php. The contents of test.php are:

```
<?php
   echo getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'); //get's the environment variable if a match
?>
```

When I navigate to the webpage, I always get a blank webpage. However if I run the script from the command line, it works as expected.

```
~> php test.php 
SG.**************************** #hidden because API key :D
```

Comment: do you really get a blank page? or do you get the source code, hidden to the naked eye because it's in tags?

Comment: How do you pass the environment variable from webserver to PHP? Show us the output for `var_dump(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));`

Comment: Look at the page source of the web page in your browser

Comment: Or that environment variable is specific to the account you login on the terminal and not available system wide

Comment: The page source is empty. `var_dump()` shows Bool(false) which means it did not find my key...:( which means the variable is not being passed to PHP. But how is it working in Terminal?

Comment: @RiggsFolly that could be it, but how to make it available system wide?

Comment: anything from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php a blank page could mean errors somewhere. Check your logs also

Comment: Sorry not an OSX user, any OSX people out there

Comment: @Fred-ii- nothing new in my error logs. my php.ini is set to display all errors.

Comment: How are you using this file as, `http://localhost` or as `file:///` directly in your browser? Or is this on a hosted site? EDIT: I guess you're using localhost, seeing your comment up there on the var_dump.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's a hosted site.

Comment: If you have a php.ini file in affect, check that it has a  variables_order directive and that the set value includes E.  FYI, values are "EGPCS" which stand for Environment, Get, Post, Cookie, and Server

Comment: @DuaneLortie Thanks Duane. I never knew that! However, it's set to EGPCS.

Comment: darn. sorry then.. that was my only idea ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What url you are using in browser? And what is your test.php file path ?

Comment: @Rishi www.yellowcabtrivalley.com/testforelmer.php; /home/raigovind93/public_html/testforelmer.php; note: no longer a blank page, because I am using `var_dump` as requested in 2nd comment.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915066