# Why does getenv not check $_SERVER on CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

According to [the documentation on `getenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php), I should be able to use it to check the `$_SERVER` variable.

```
<?php
// Example use of getenv()
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

// Or simply use a Superglobal ($_SERVER or $_ENV)
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

However, this only seems to work for me when run from a web server (Apache), but not from the command line. The `$_SERVER` variable is populated correctly in both cases, but `getenv` only reads it on the web server.

```
<?php
var_dump(  getenv('SCRIPT_FILENAME'));
var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

Output on Apache to browser:

> /var/www/localhost/questions-answers/scratch.php:7:
>   string '/var/www/localhost/questions-answers/scratch.php' (length=48)
>   /var/www/localhost/questions-answers/scratch.php:8:
>   string '/var/www/localhost/questions-answers/scratch.php' (length=48)

Output on CLI:

> /var/www/localhost/questions-answers/scratch.php:7:
>   bool(false)
>   /var/www/localhost/questions-answers/scratch.php:8:
>   string(11) "scratch.php"

I feel like there's some missing option to set in my `php.ini` but I can't find any reference for that suspicion. This is the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23915066/4233593).

Comment: There is a difference between an environment variable and php's superglobal variables. What makes you certain that `$_SERVER` should be an environment variable in CLI usage?

Comment: @arkascha the example on http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php but I see what you're saying. Thanks, I didn't realize it wasn't possible, especially considering the comments on that page referring to it working in CLI.

Comment: I don't see that the example says that it should be an environment variable... I suggest you simply compare `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV` to get an overview...

Comment: @arkascha I don't understand what you mean. Do you see the example `$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); // Or simply use a Superglobal ($_SERVER or $_ENV) $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: especially with all the comments about its case-insensitivity.

Comment: Sure, but where does it say that the sets of superglobals and environment variables are identical in all situations?