# How to get batch (cmd) variables in php?

Tags: php, batch-file, variables, cmd

So here is what I am trying to do. I have two files: `.bat` and `.php`

**run.bat:**

```
set password = ok123
php -f data.php
```

**data.php:**

```
<?php
$pass = %password%;
echo '.$password.'
```

I need to pass the password from the bat file to the php script.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting environment variables for accessing in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the PHP script like this, as you dont want to place a password in an
 environment variable

```
php data.php paswd123
```

data.php

```
<?php
if ( $argc < 2 ) {
    echo 'call this script using the password as a parameter';
    exit;
}

$password = $argv[1];
```

> The manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Thanks alot sir! , belive me i have searched for this answer but i forget to read about the above link that you have given to me .
Anyway , it has worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
set password = ok123
```

will set a variable "password " to " ok123".

spaces are significant on both sides of a string `set` statement. Lose the spaces!

Comment: Thanks , i should have done it like this :
set "password=ok123"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set environment variables, like you did with `set` command, you can access them in PHP using `$_ENV` array. So in your situation password will be stored as `$_ENV['password']`.