# How can I use php to populate a manifest.json file?

Tags: php, json, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a manifest.json file that loads correctly when placed in the root directory of my wesite. Instead of it being a static file, I would like to use php variables from within my site to populate the values inside of the manifest.

I can't find any information on this [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/), and I'm not sure if it's possible.

I've tried switching the name of my manifest to `manifest.php` and used `header('Content-Type: application/json')` within it.

Inside my index file head:

```
<script src="<?php echo $SITE_URL;?>/main.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $SITE_URL;?>/sw.js"></script>
<link rel="manifest" href="<?php echo $SITE_URL;?>/manifest.php">
```

Inside my manifest.php:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo "
{
  \"name\": \"$SiteName\",
  \"gcm_user_visible_only\": true,
  \"short_name\": \"$Name\",
  \"description\": \"$PageDescription.\",
  \"start_url\": \"/index.php\",
  \"display\": \"standalone\",
  \"orientation\": \"portrait\",
  \"background_color\": \"$darkblue\",
  \"theme_color\": \"#f0f0f0\",
  \"icons\": [{
    \"src\": \"logo-load.png\",
    \"sizes\": \"96x96 128x128 144x144\",
    \"type\": \"image/png\"
  },{
    \"src\": \"logo-icon.png\",
    \"sizes\": \"48x48 72x72\",
    \"type\": \"image/png\"     
  }]
}
";
?>
```

The variables `$SiteName, $Name, $PageDescription, $darkblue, etc` are all defined within my document head before the manifest.php is loaded.

Is what I'm trying possible?

Comment: This should work just fine. Are you getting valid JSON from manifest.php? You could look at building out an array and using `json_encode` - might be easier to catch issues. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I am getting valid JSON, but with missing values (where the php should be).   Going to use json_encode and see if results vary

Comment: Well, where is `$SiteName` assigned a value? Your code "works" as is.

Answer (score 3):

Main question I have is where are these constants pulled from? Sometimes people set them at the server host level and import them ([environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php)). Another option (sort of blurs with what you are doing) is to [parse an INI file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

I would do something like the following:

```
<?php

$siteName = 'foo';
$name = 'bar';
$pageDescription = 'baz';

$manifest = [
    "name" => $siteName,
    "gcm_user_visible_only" => true,
    "short_name" => $name,
    "description" => $pageDescription,
    "start_url" => "/index.php",
    "display" => "standalone",
    "orientation" => "portrait",
    "background_color" => $darkblue,
    "theme_color" => "#f0f0f0",
    "icons" => [
        "src" => "logo-load.png",
        "sizes"=> "96x96 128x128 144x144",
        "type" => "image/png"
    ],
    "src" => "logo-icon.png",
    "sizes" => "48x48 72x72",
    "type" => "image/png"
];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($manifest);
```

Comment: The variables are just strings inside of the index.php file, before the manifest.php is called. What you've posted here works, however when I move the `$siteName` to my index file it is registered as `null`

Comment: Scope. Luckily [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is a thing of the past... May you never know the pain of variable collisions! Take a look at how you [define a constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) or... we'll explore options once you have better understanding of scope.