# How do I deal with the .env file when deploying Symfony on shared hosting

Tags: symfony, deployment

I'm using Symfony 4 and Hostgator's shared hosting.

I'm trying to deploy my app to the site. I have uploaded the app to the server and then moved and configured the index.php to the public_html folder. When I ran the site I got this error on the .env file.

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the
>   "/home4/xxx/public_html/yyy/../.env" environment file. in
>   /home4/xxx/yyy/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:54 Stack trace: #0
>   /home4/xxx/public_html/yyy/index.php(15):
>   Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('/home4/xxx/pu...') #1 {main}
>   thrown in /home4/xxx/yyy/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 54

I have read that the environmental file should only be use on development stage, that's probably why the exception. But then what exactly I need to do next?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your error it looks like a permissions issue. 
Double check your folders have `(drwxr-xr-x)/(755)` and files have `(-rw-r--r--)/(644)`.

This may also help you in your setup: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Additional Information:

Symfony uses the .env in any environment other than production. Production environment is set using server variables `APP_ENV=prod`. If it is not set, it is loading from the .env file. `public/index.php` will give you a little more insight.

Comment: I checked, all the folders are 755 permission and all the files are 644 permission. And I don't understand what you mean by server variable, where do I set this?

Comment: Here is a good link, if your using Apache. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902492/9191229. Do you have console access?

Comment: So basically I will need to have access to the console on the server in order to change environment setting? I don't see anything in my control panel about console.

Comment: I found the problem. it was in the index.php that I forgot to update the path for the .env file, I only changed the one for the autoload

Comment: @reddy nice job!