# How to set aws DB constants in my local apache (php)?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, constants

Amazon AWS (LAMP) automatically adds DB param constants so that it’s not necessary to mention them explicitly in the php: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html. How can I replicate this on my local (windows) instance? I saw define, but that needs to go in the php file, which defeats the purpose I think. There must be a better way to achieve this, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QA referenced in Jose Henrique Felipetto ([Setting environment variables for accessing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php)) answered this question. I have put in a close vote on my own question, and closed it as a duplicate