# How pass system environments to apache php

Tags: php, apache

I have docker image that pass environments to container

```
environment:
  MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER:-mysql}
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-mysql}
  MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE:-test}
```

They are in container

```
$ printenv
HOSTNAME=cd5041be5b83
PWD=/
MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysql
MYSQL_USER=mysql
HOME=/root
MYSQL_DATABASE=test
```

Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "/app/code"
  ErrorLog /app/log/error.log
  CustomLog /app/log/requests.log combined

  PassEnv MYSQL_USER MYSQL_PASSWORD

  <Directory "/app/code">
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to get them they not exist in

```
var_dump(getenv());
var_dump($_ENV);
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting environment variables for accessing in PHP when using Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php-when-using-apache)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No, it set env, but I need to apache take env from system and pass it to php