# PostgreSQL - storing db credentials in Apache2 httpd.conf

Tags: postgresql, apache2, php

I have a PHP application that needs to connect to a Postgres database and I don't want to store the credentials in a config file outside the web tree, if I can help it. I installed the pgsql module.

I read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146354/setting-php-variables-in-httpd-conf) and like the idea of putting them in httpd.conf

I was wondering if anyone has figured out a way to store PostgreSQL db credentials in httpd.conf.

There are no predefined php.ini directives for PostgreSQL PHP module like there are for MySQL PHP module, as far as I can tell:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

```
php_value mysql.default.user      myusername
php_value mysql.default.password  mypassword
php_value mysql.default.host      server
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware that such options exist for PostgreSQL. What exactly are your objections  against storing the settings in a config-file? Imo storing them inside php_value settings may even be more dangerous, not sure, but will they be output by phpinfo()? If you don't want to store credentials at-all, it's possible to set a 'trust' authentication for a user from the local machine, this way a local user doesn't have to provide a password (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html).

Comment: As long as you don't set them as server environment variables, they won't show up in php.ini so I think I'm OK there. This is a remote connection so not sure if Postgres trusted auth would work.

Comment: Trusted connections *are* possible from a remote server and can be specified for a certain user and host/ip-address, however SSL Certificate authentication may be more appropriate in that case

Comment: I just tested setting the mysql.default_ settings in my php.ini and they DO appear in phpinfo() output: http://jsfiddle.net/MTPy9/ ok, phpinfo() should *never* be present on your website, but still

Comment: Well, that's not good...

Comment: I wonder if setting them in httpd.conf VS. php.ini obfuscates them, I will try it and see

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference. You're setting the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

1. The best option, if you can do it, is to use certificate auth and a client certificate.
2. The second best option if you can is to use a .pgpass file, which would store this in the home directory of the user that Apache runs as.
3. Your third option is you could use `mod_rewrite` to set the `PGUSER` and `PGPASSWORD` environment variables.  Note that this is pretty dangerous because anyone on the server could access the environment and learn the username and password.